# .Net 5.0 - In case of multiple attribute routes defined on an action, query parameter always comes as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

In .Net 5.0 API, I have an action on which I have applied multiple attribute routes as defined below

```
[HttpGet, Route("Get/{id?}"), Route("{id}")]
public void Get(long id)
{
   //do something
}
```

With this routing, the following paths work fine

1. ```
   api/Controller/1
   ```
2. ```
   api/Controller/Get/1
   ```

However, if I pass the id as a query parameter, I always get 0 in 'id'.

e.g.

```
api/Controller/Get?id=1.
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue and how it can be fixed?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry it is not null, I am getting a 0.

Comment: Both of your attributes say that the `id` parameter is binded from the path. Did you mean to use the `[FromQuery]` attribute?

Comment: @gunr2171: No I don't want to use [FromQuery] as it would not allow the case when id is passed in the path.

Comment: Why do you need to allow multiple paths?

Comment: I assume the period at the end of your last url is a typo, and not something you're submitting?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes it is a typo

Answer (score 1):

Just tested using both net 5 and net 6 , VS 2022 and Postman

```
api/Controller/Get?id=1
```

it is working properly

I've used this  controller, action

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpGet, Route("Get/{id?}"), Route("{id}")]
public void Get(long id)
{
   //do something
}
...
}
```

UPDATE

but if I add  [ApiController] attribute then query string id is 0

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

It seems that ApiController is not supposed to have a query string at all. It doesn't work even if I change route to this

```
[HttpGet, Route("Get}")]
public void Get(long id)
{
   //do something
}
```

UPDATE 2

See PO answer how to make ApiController to accept the parameters from a query string.

Comment: Have you tested it in .Net 5.0? If I remember correctly, I think it used to work in .net framework 4.7.x.

Comment: I tested this in .net6 and failed. Also tested an empty route.

Comment: @Firewizz I didnt test just a controller route, since I have a lot of APIs

Comment: I am also testing it with VS 2019 and Postman, but it does not work.

Comment: I'll back up Serge. Just made his code in an empty .Net 5 ASP.Net project in VS 2022. Tested all three urls the OP gave (though it was "My" rather than the word "Controller"), and all three worked just fine.

Comment: Yea I tried this also with [ApiController] (and didnt work).

Comment: But strange this is, if I omit both Routes, it works with querystrings..  Just [HttpGet] and the parameter..

Comment: @gunr2171: I tried with VS 2019 .Net 5 api project but the query string id does not work for me. I don't think it should be linked to VS version.

Comment: No it looks like it is the combination of usage of [ApiController] and using a Route. If you don't route OR only use a blank route it works. But if you add a route that is not blank and uses parameters from the uri it fails.

Comment: I think this could be of massive help binding from both [FromQuery, FromRoute]. https://www.seeleycoder.com/blog/mixed-model-binding-aspnetcore/

Comment: And another good article for hybrid binding: https://github.com/billbogaiv/hybrid-model-binding

Comment: Thanks, gunr2171 and @Firewizz for identifying the issue. I set the SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters property to true and now it seems to work both APIController and Route attribute.

Comment: @Serge I think you should update your answer. Removing [ApiController] is not the right approach IMO. [ApiController] (attribute enables a few features including attribute routing requirement, automatic model validation and binding source parameter inference.). You should include OPs answer because that is the real/best solution in this case.

Comment: @Firewizz Sorry about this,  I just posted the research that shows that API doesn't accept query string. This is was the pourpose of my post.  And if API is removed everything is working fine.

Comment: I seem to recall `[FromQuery]` still works as expected. Have you tried that?

Comment: @TanveerBadar yes, it works if you add [FromQuery], but we need from route too

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be with `[APIController]` attribute along with the `[Route]` attribute. I set the `SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters` to `true` and it seemed to have resolved the issue and now all three URL formats work.

```
     services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
    });
```

Update:
For Post and Put requests, you need to add [FromBody] attribute before parameter.